# При появлении клавиатуры на Android фоновая fixed картинка с bottom: 0 уезжает вверх. Как сделать, чтобы не уезжала, но была прижата книзу?

Tags: html, css

При появлении клавиатуры на Android фоновая `fixed` картинка с `bottom: 0` уезжает вверх. Как сделать так, чтобы не уезжала, но была прижата книзу? Вот сайт, если что. У картинки класс `bg-img`.

http://lev-rodionov.ru/